# Add header to .data file in Pandas

Tags: pandas, read-fwf

Given a file with the extention of `.data`, I have read it with `pd.read_fwf("./input.data", sep=",", header = None)`:

Out:

```
    0
0   63.0,1.0,1.0,145.0,233.0,1.0,2.0,150.0,0.0,2.3...
1   67.0,1.0,4.0,160.0,286.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,1.0,1.5...
2   67.0,1.0,4.0,120.0,229.0,0.0,2.0,129.0,1.0,2.6...
3   37.0,1.0,3.0,130.0,250.0,0.0,0.0,187.0,0.0,3.5...
4   41.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,204.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,1.4...
... ...
292 57.0,0.0,4.0,140.0,241.0,0.0,0.0,123.0,1.0,0.2...
293 45.0,1.0,1.0,110.0,264.0,0.0,0.0,132.0,0.0,1.2...
294 68.0,1.0,4.0,144.0,193.0,1.0,0.0,141.0,0.0,3.4...
295 57.0,1.0,4.0,130.0,131.0,0.0,0.0,115.0,1.0,1.2...
296 57.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,236.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0.0...
```

How can I add the following column names to it? Thanks.

```
col_names = ["age", "sex", "cp", "restbp", "chol", "fbs", "restecg", 
           "thalach", "exang", "oldpeak", "slope", "ca", "thal", "num"]
```

**Update:**

```
pd.read_fwf("./input.data", names = col_names)
```

Out:

```
    age sex cp  restbp  chol    fbs restecg thalach exang   oldpeak slope   ca  thal    num
0   63.0,1.0,1.0,145.0,233.0,1.0,2.0,150.0,0.0,2.3...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   67.0,1.0,4.0,160.0,286.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,1.0,1.5...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   67.0,1.0,4.0,120.0,229.0,0.0,2.0,129.0,1.0,2.6...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   37.0,1.0,3.0,130.0,250.0,0.0,0.0,187.0,0.0,3.5...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   41.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,204.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,1.4...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
292 57.0,0.0,4.0,140.0,241.0,0.0,0.0,123.0,1.0,0.2...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
293 45.0,1.0,1.0,110.0,264.0,0.0,0.0,132.0,0.0,1.2...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
294 68.0,1.0,4.0,144.0,193.0,1.0,0.0,141.0,0.0,3.4...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
295 57.0,1.0,4.0,130.0,131.0,0.0,0.0,115.0,1.0,1.2...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
296 57.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,236.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0.0...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: How working `pd.read_csv("./input.data", names=col_names)` ?

Comment: Is your file a `fixed width` file or a `csv`? That makes a huge difference in which method to use.

Comment: The problem solved by `read_csv`. :)

Comment: @ahbon thank you for your update outlying the `names` parameter. That was exactly what I needed and it is not currently documented for the `read_fwf` function.

Comment: I'm glad it helps you, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If check [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

> Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame.

So if there is separator `,` use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
col_names = ["age", "sex", "cp", "restbp", "chol", "fbs", "restecg", 
           "thalach", "exang", "oldpeak", "slope", "ca", "thal", "num"]

df = pd.read_csv("input.data", names=col_names)
print (df)

      age  sex   cp  restbp   chol  fbs  restecg  thalach  exang  oldpeak  \
0    63.0  1.0  1.0   145.0  233.0  1.0      2.0    150.0    0.0      2.3   
1    67.0  1.0  4.0   160.0  286.0  0.0      2.0    108.0    1.0      1.5   
2    67.0  1.0  4.0   120.0  229.0  0.0      2.0    129.0    1.0      2.6   
3    37.0  1.0  3.0   130.0  250.0  0.0      0.0    187.0    0.0      3.5   
4    41.0  0.0  2.0   130.0  204.0  0.0      2.0    172.0    0.0      1.4   
..    ...  ...  ...     ...    ...  ...      ...      ...    ...      ...   
292  57.0  0.0  4.0   140.0  241.0  0.0      0.0    123.0    1.0      0.2   
293  45.0  1.0  1.0   110.0  264.0  0.0      0.0    132.0    0.0      1.2   
294  68.0  1.0  4.0   144.0  193.0  1.0      0.0    141.0    0.0      3.4   
295  57.0  1.0  4.0   130.0  131.0  0.0      0.0    115.0    1.0      1.2   
296  57.0  0.0  2.0   130.0  236.0  0.0      2.0    174.0    0.0      0.0   

     slope   ca  thal  num  
0      3.0  0.0   6.0    0  
1      2.0  3.0   3.0    1  
2      2.0  2.0   7.0    1  
3      3.0  0.0   3.0    0  
4      1.0  0.0   3.0    0  
..     ...  ...   ...  ...  
292    2.0  0.0   7.0    1  
293    2.0  0.0   7.0    1  
294    2.0  2.0   7.0    1  
295    2.0  1.0   7.0    1  
296    2.0  1.0   3.0    1  

[297 rows x 14 columns]
```

Comment: I have tried with this, but get many columns with `NaN`s. I also add `sep=','`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ahbon - one idea, how working add parameter `quoting=3` for no `quoting` ?

Comment: I have added `quoting=3`, the result didn't change.

Comment: @ahbon - Are data confidental? It seems some data related issue

Comment: Sorry, I have used `read_fwf ` instead of `read_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `read_csv` without header and pass `col_names`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.data', header=None, names=col_names);
```

Output (head):

```
      age    sex    cp    restbp    chol    fbs    restecg    thalach    exang    oldpeak    slope    ca    thal    num
--  -----  -----  ----  --------  ------  -----  ---------  ---------  -------  ---------  -------  ----  ------  -----
 0     63      1     1       145     233      1          2        150        0        2.3        3     0       6      0
 1     67      1     4       160     286      0          2        108        1        1.5        2     3       3      1
 2     67      1     4       120     229      0          2        129        1        2.6        2     2       7      1
 3     37      1     3       130     250      0          0        187        0        3.5        3     0       3      0
 4     41      0     2       130     204      0          2        172        0        1.4        1     0       3      0
```

Comment: header=None is not necessary,

Comment: because if passed `names` then pandas be default set `header=None`